# Find the original index of sorted array

Tags: java, android, arrays

Suppose I have an array of String like this

```
String [] item={"B","C","D","A"};
```

that means

```
item[0]=B

item[1]=C

item[2]=D

item[3]=A
```

Now I have sorted this array and gets like

```
item[0]=A

item[1]=B

item[2]=C

item[3]=D
```

I want to know the original index of element C(which is 1 here ) . How to find that using code? May be my question is not clear ,please ask me anything you did not understand .

Comment: Can you have duplicated values? like {"B","C","B","A","D","A"};?

Comment: No, Actually i just wanted to get the original index

Comment: Is it in your array contain only unique values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot unless you save some additinal data. You could e.g. put both index and value inside a class and sort by value, or you could define a array containing the indices and sort that array instead:

```
Integer[] indices = new Integer[item.length];
for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    indices[i] = i;
}

Arrays.sort(indices, new Comparator<Integer>() {

    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return item[i1].compareTo(item[i2]);
    }
});
```

Sorted values:

```
item[indices[0]]
item[indices[1]]
item[indices[2]]
item[indices[3]]
```

Original indices

```
indices[0]
indices[1]
indices[2]
indices[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

After you sorted your array. How can you trace your original position?

I come to mind just 3 options:

1. Save all the swaps you did during the sort process
2. Save an original copy of the vector
3. Use a structure where you save actual position and original position.

Answer (score 0):

Before you sort the array use a map to store original indexes of your array elements as follows.

```
String[] item = { "B", "C", "D", "A" };
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    map.put(item[i], i);
}
```

when you need you call as follows

```
map.get("A"); // here return the original index of "A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Recap: you have two arrays, *unsortedArray* and *sortedArray*. For each element of *sortedArray*, you want to retrieve the corresponding index in *unsortedArray*.

```
public int getCorrespondingIndex(String[] unsortedArray, String[] sortedArray, int index){
   for(int i=0; i<unsortedArray.length; i++)
     if(sortedArray[index].equals(unsortedAray[i])
       return i;
   return -1;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
  int oldIndex;
  String[] unsortedArray = {"B","C","D","A"};
  String[] sortedArray= {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
  for(i=0; i<sortedArray.length; i++){
    oldIndex = getCorrespondingIndex(unsortedArray, sortedArray, i);
    System.out.println("The element "+sortedArray[i]+" was in position "+oldIndex);
}
```